# Which LEGO set is this vehicle assembly from?

Tags: set-identification

I found this in my LEGO box. I’ve looked up the brick numbers to try and identify, but I can’t for the life of me figure out what set it’s from or a part of. Looks fairly recent, though I have LEGO sets that are at least 30+ years old. It’s not something I would have built without a plan. Would appreciate the help! I’d like to find the rest of the parts and finish it!

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It is a 4x4 from [Extreme Team Challenge (6584)](https://brickset.com/sets/6584-1/Extreme-Team-Challenge) set released in 1998.

[image]